# Run powershell script in taskfile.yml

Tags: powershell

I'm using [task](https://github.com/go-task/task/) to set environment variables with a Powershell script.

While running `develop.ps1` alone works fine, it fails when I use task and run `task dev-api`.

My Taskfile.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'

vars:
  WEBAPI_PROJ: WebApi

tasks:
  dev-api:
    dir: Src/{{.WEBAPI_PROJ}}
    cmds:
      - echo '{{OS}}'
      - '\develop.ps1'
```

The error message:

```
task: echo 'windows'
windows
task: \develop.ps1
task: Failed to run task "dev-api": fork/exec C:\Users\Wenchin\Desktop\MyProject\Src\WebApi\develop.ps1: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Does anyone know how I can run a powershell script with `task`?

Comment: Don't know `task`, but it looks like it's trying to execute a Powershell script without invoking Powershell.exe. Try passing powershell's executable as a command too.

Comment: @vonPryz thanks for the comment. I updated the line to `Powershell.exe -File \develop.ps1` and it works now.

Comment: That's great. Consider writing (and accepting) your own answer to the question. If someone else has the same problem, the answer's easy enough to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the line to `Powershell.exe -File \develop.ps1` and it works now.

I also added a conditional statement to execute command according to the OS.

Updated Taskfile.yml:

```sh
version: '3'

vars:
  WEBAPI_PROJ: WebApi

tasks:
  dev-api:
    dir: Src/{{.WEBAPI_PROJ}}
    cmds:
      - echo '{{OS}}'
      - '{{if eq OS "windows"}}Powershell.exe -File \develop.ps1{{else}}bash develop.sh{{end}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Task version v3.23.0 and you can create platform specific commands. (v.3.11.0 does not support this; I cannot figure out when it was implemented)

The taskfile would be:

```yaml
version: '3'

vars:
  WEBAPI_PROJ: WebApi

tasks:
  dev-api:
    dir: Src/{{.WEBAPI_PROJ}}
    cmds:
      - cmd: Powershell.exe -File develop.sp1
        platform: [windows]
      - cmd: bash develop.sh
        platform: [linux] # [linux, darwin]
```

I think this is a cleaner way to achieve what @wenchin77 suggested, given the support for os specific commands and jobs in general.